# MvvmCross show view before going further

Tags: c#, xamarin, task, mvvmcross

I have an application where I can use popup views over the normal windows.
For getting the data the user needs to login so I have a token.
Has anyone experience with the way if there is no token, show first a view, then go further where you was heading to?

To make it more clear:

```
public void Init()
{
    if (!CheckToken())
    {
       Task.Run(() => ShowViewModel<InsertPasswordViewModel>())
                    .ContinueWith(t => GetData());
    }
    else
    {
        //Do your thing
        GetData();
    }
 }
```

The problem now is that the task is run so view is shown and immediately starts GetData but he has no token and crashes.

Any ideas or fixes are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do navigation in `Init`. You are essentially navigating away from a page you are in the middle of navigating to. The navigation isn't finished executing when `Init` is called.

You are not getting a result from `ShowViewModel` either, so you can't rely on that returning anything when you are done with everything in `InsertPasswordViewModel`.

What you are probably looking for is navigating to your `ViewModel` with some kind of parameter telling where you came from. Then let `InsertPasswordViewModel` use that parameter to navigate back once password is OK.
You probably want to modify the View hierarchy too, which you can do through a custom presenter and a set of presentation hints.

Comment: Hi Cheesbaron, thanks for your clear answer. I am aware of preventing to navigate via the init, however on a other view I got it work with a Task.Delay. I have less experience with the MvxBundle but I think I should use it more.

Comment: do you know where an example can be found of the MvxRequestedBy?

Comment: It is just an enum. It isn't used anywhere and has been removed in 5.x. Just set it to anything.

Comment: good to know. Last question, do you know a (very) simple example how the chaining can be done with viewmodels? Like, open ModelView1. When closed go to ModelView2. (To make it more clear, before gettingData you should be loggedin, so check is loggedin, if not show login and go further, else getdata)

Comment: I'll see if I can write up something soon